# Адаптация таблицы под мобильные устройства

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, табличная-верстка

Есть психологический тест, сделан в виде таблицы. Вся тема **Wordpress** прекрасно адаптирована под мобильные, но страница с тестом просто обрезается(нет ни прокрутки, ни переноса текста на следующую строку). Гуглила как средствами **css** с помощью `@media` адаптировать таблицу, но все нагугленное у меня не сработало.  Пробовала таблицу оборачивать в `div` и ему назначать `overflow-x: scroll;` Пробовала варьировать `word-break: break-all;` - ничего. Подскажите, что может помочь?

```css
<style>

   .circle {
     width:30px;
     height:30px;
     display:inline-block;
     border-radius:50px;
     -moz-border-radius:50px;
     -webkit-border-radius:50px;
     -khtml-border-radius:50px;
     font-size:15px; color:#fff;
     line-height:30px;
     text-align:center;
     background:#83bcb6
     
     
   }
   
   
    
    .blueButton {
    background:  #83bcb6; 
    font-size:18px; 
    color:#fff;
     width:100px;
     height:30px;
     text-align:center;
   }
   
   input.hidden{
   display: none;
}
   
</style>
```

```html
<?php $home = 'http://' .  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) . '/'; 
?>

<form  action="<?= $home ?>result.php" method="POST" target="_self">
<fieldset>
   
<div class="table-container">
<table  width = "100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-collapse="collapse" >

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="5" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">1</span></td>
     <td align="left"  width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Представьтесь, пожалуйста</span></td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="5" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><input type="text" required name="uname" >
         <input type="text" class="hidden" name="spam">
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 2------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;"><span class="circle">2</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none non marging: 0px;e;"><span>Ваш возраст</span></td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;"><input type="text" required name="age" size="2" >
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 3------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">3</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш пол</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left"  style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="M"> М</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="W"> Ж</label>
        <p></p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 4------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">4</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; overflow: auto;"><span>Насколько Вы удовлетворены своей жизнью в текущем периоде? От 1 до 10 </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left"  width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <input type="text" required name="satisfaction" size="2" >
        <p></p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 5------------------------ -->

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">5</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Как бы вы охарактеризовали свою жизненную ситуацию </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q61" value="1"> Понимание, что жизнь проходит, и она мне не нравится
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q62" value="2"> Тупик, болото, застой, «стеклянный потолок», через которые не могу пройти
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q63" value="3"> Есть конкретная «хроническая» проблема, пробовал разные способы, не могу решить
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q64" value="4"> У меня кризис среднего возраста
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q65" value="5"> Апатия, утрата смысла, жизнь проходит мимо
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q66" value="6"> Именно сейчас я столкнулся с «нерешаемой» ситуацией, не знаю, что делать
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q67" value="7"> Не понимаю, что именно со мной происходит? и хочу разобраться
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q68" value="8"> Достиг всего, что хотел, что дальше?
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q69" value="9"> Другое (место для описания)</label>
        <p></p>
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 6------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">6</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Пожалуйста, выберите жизненные сферы из списка, которыми Вы не удовлетворены </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere1" value="1">     Самореализация
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere2" value="2">     Семья
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere3" value="3" >     Финансы
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere4" value="4">     Внутренняя
     гармония, отношение к себе
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere5" value="5">     Дом (физическое обиталище)
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere6" value="6" >     Работа
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere7" value="7">     Воспитание детей
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere8" value="8">     Внешний вид
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere9" value="9" >     Любовь
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere10" value="10" >     Друзья
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere11" value="11">     Отдых и удовольствия
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere12" value="12">     Здоровье и физическая форма
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere13" value="13" >     Обучение и персональное развитие
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere14" value="14" >     Другое
    <p>
     <textarea name="textarea1" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
    </p>
   
     
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 7------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">7</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли у вас что-то из перечисленного. Отметьте один признак и только в том случае, если вы уверены в нем </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="1"> Как будто что-то невидимое держит и не пускает. Всякая попытка продвинуться в жизни заканчивается тратой сил и впечатлением, будто невидимая «резинка» возвращает на место</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="2"> Ощущение, что живу внутри стеклянной банки (круга, обруча), который отделяет меня от другого мира</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="3"> Чувствую себя как-то не в себе, будто кто-то управляет извне</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="4"> Ощущение, что мне в жизни нет места</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="5"> Кажется, что я застыл в плену проблемы</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="6"> В моей семье были самоубийства, много несчастных случаев, психозы и т.д.</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="7"> Аварии, серьезные травмы за последние 1-2 года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="8"> Некоторые члены в системе отсутствуют (например, внебрачный ребенок отца) или утаивается чья-то судьба (например, о дедушке говорят, что он умер от инфаркта, хотя он покончил с собой)</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="9"> Я пережил тяжелый травмирующий опыт (прежде всего, в раннем детстве, например, ранее отлучение от матери, насилие)</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="10"> Страхи или фобии, которые являются для меня явной проблемой</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="11"> Я испытываю странные, тяжелые чувства, не объяснимые с точки зрения моей реальной жизненной ситуации</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="12"> Я испытываю чувство вины буквально за все</label>
     
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 8------------------------ -->

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">8</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Как бы Вы сформулировали, в случае обращения за помощью, свой основной запрос? </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <textarea name="textarea2" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea> 
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 9----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">9</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Проходили ли вы психотерапию за последние 1-2 года?  </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 10----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">10</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли у вас в настоящее время  </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb1" value="1"> Панические атаки
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb2" value="2"> Клаустрофобия (боязнь замкнутого пространства)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb3" value="3"> Аэрофобия (боязнь перелетов на самолете)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb4" value="4"> Навязчивые мысли и ритуалы (постоянно мыть руки, все время перепроверять утюг/ключи и т.п)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb51" value="5"> Другое
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea3" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>

<!-- 11----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">11</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Принимаете ли вы антидепрессанты, транквилизаторы   </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl4" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl4" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 12----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">12</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Не так давно я пережил тяжелую для себя ситуацию   </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl5" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl5" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 13----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">13</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Консультирование в каком виде вы предпочтете (все виды консультирования не привязаны к вашему географическому положению и доступны из любой точки мира)</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="1"> Индивидуальное консультирование (целенаправленное решение наболевших проблем с профессионалом)</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="2"> Он-лайн проект (аудио-, видео- в записи), который позволяет всесторонне изменить жизнь за полгода, самостоятельно или с поддержкой профессионала </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="3"> Я хочу работать только очно, и готов совместить коучинг с поездкой на Адриатику (Черногория), вышлите мне, пожалуйста, больше информации (проект «Коучинг на Адриатике»)</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 14----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">14</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Я знаю про проект Евгении Соловьевой «Место Силы и Любви»</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="1"> первый день</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="2"> 1-2 месяца</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="3"> около полугода</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="4"> менее года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="5"> 1-2 года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="6"> 3-5 лет</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="7"> давно</label>
    <p></p>
   
     </td>
     </tr>
<!-- 15----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">15</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Укажите, пожалуйста, Ваш город</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
       <p>
         <input type="text" required name="city" >
       </p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 16----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">16</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span> Ваша должность / кем Вы работаете?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
       <input type="text"  name="work" >
       <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 17----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">17</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш e-mail</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <input type="email" required name="emailaddr" >
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 18----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">18</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Я узнал о вас из</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="1"> От знакомых </label>
        <p></p>
        <label> Интернет: </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="2"> Яндекс</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="3"> Google</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="4"> YouTube</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="5"> Вконтакте</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="6"> Facebook</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="7"> Другие сайты</label>
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 19----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">19</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Какую информацию вы искали, когда нашли проект «Место Силы и Любви»?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea4" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 20----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">20</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Укажите, как бы Вы хотели получить наши рекомендации?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <label><input name="radioControl7" type="radio" value="1"> Прошу прислать мне рекомендации по электронной почте </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl7" type="radio" value="2"> Позвоните мне, пожалуйста, я хочу обсудить варианты работы по Скайп (в течение 1-2 дней)</label>
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 21----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">21</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш Skype</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <input type="text" required name="skype" >
        <p></p>
           
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 22----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">22</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли еще что-то, о чем вы хотели сообщить нам</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea5" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
           
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- Result----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <button type="submit" class="blueButton" > Результат </button>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оберните дивом всю форму тогда заработает. Почему внутри формы не работает не знаю.

```css
 .circle {
     width:30px;
     height:30px;
     display:inline-block;
     border-radius:50px;
     -moz-border-radius:50px;
     -webkit-border-radius:50px;
     -khtml-border-radius:50px;
     font-size:15px; color:#fff;
     line-height:30px;
     text-align:center;
     background:#83bcb6
     
     
   }
   
   
    
    .blueButton {
    background:  #83bcb6; 
    font-size:18px; 
    color:#fff;
     width:100px;
     height:30px;
     text-align:center;
   }
   
   input.hidden{
   display: none;
}
.table-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
<form  action="<?= $home ?>result.php" method="POST" target="_self">
<fieldset>
   

<table  width = "100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-collapse="collapse" >

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="5" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">1</span></td>
     <td align="left"  width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Представьтесь, пожалуйста</span></td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="5" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><input type="text" required name="uname" >
         <input type="text" class="hidden" name="spam">
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 2------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;"><span class="circle">2</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none non marging: 0px;e;"><span>Ваш возраст</span></td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; marging: 0px;"><input type="text" required name="age" size="2" >
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 3------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">3</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш пол</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left"  style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="M"> М</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="W"> Ж</label>
        <p></p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 4------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">4</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none; overflow: auto;"><span>Насколько Вы удовлетворены своей жизнью в текущем периоде? От 1 до 10 </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left"  width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <input type="text" required name="satisfaction" size="2" >
        <p></p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 5------------------------ -->

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">5</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Как бы вы охарактеризовали свою жизненную ситуацию </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="q61" value="1"> Понимание, что жизнь проходит, и она мне не нравится
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q62" value="2"> Тупик, болото, застой, «стеклянный потолок», через которые не могу пройти
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q63" value="3"> Есть конкретная «хроническая» проблема, пробовал разные способы, не могу решить
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q64" value="4"> У меня кризис среднего возраста
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q65" value="5"> Апатия, утрата смысла, жизнь проходит мимо
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q66" value="6"> Именно сейчас я столкнулся с «нерешаемой» ситуацией, не знаю, что делать
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q67" value="7"> Не понимаю, что именно со мной происходит? и хочу разобраться
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q68" value="8"> Достиг всего, что хотел, что дальше?
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q69" value="9"> Другое (место для описания)</label>
        <p></p>
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 6------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">6</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Пожалуйста, выберите жизненные сферы из списка, которыми Вы не удовлетворены </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere1" value="1">     Самореализация
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere2" value="2">     Семья
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere3" value="3" >     Финансы
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere4" value="4">     Внутренняя
     гармония, отношение к себе
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere5" value="5">     Дом (физическое обиталище)
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere6" value="6" >     Работа
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere7" value="7">     Воспитание детей
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere8" value="8">     Внешний вид
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere9" value="9" >     Любовь
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere10" value="10" >     Друзья
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere11" value="11">     Отдых и удовольствия
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere12" value="12">     Здоровье и физическая форма
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere13" value="13" >     Обучение и персональное развитие
     <p></p>
     <input type="checkbox" name="unsat_sphere14" value="14" >     Другое
    <p>
     <textarea name="textarea1" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
    </p>
   
     
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 7------------------------ -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">7</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли у вас что-то из перечисленного. Отметьте один признак и только в том случае, если вы уверены в нем </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="1"> Как будто что-то невидимое держит и не пускает. Всякая попытка продвинуться в жизни заканчивается тратой сил и впечатлением, будто невидимая «резинка» возвращает на место</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="2"> Ощущение, что живу внутри стеклянной банки (круга, обруча), который отделяет меня от другого мира</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="3"> Чувствую себя как-то не в себе, будто кто-то управляет извне</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="4"> Ощущение, что мне в жизни нет места</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="5"> Кажется, что я застыл в плену проблемы</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="6"> В моей семье были самоубийства, много несчастных случаев, психозы и т.д.</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="7"> Аварии, серьезные травмы за последние 1-2 года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="8"> Некоторые члены в системе отсутствуют (например, внебрачный ребенок отца) или утаивается чья-то судьба (например, о дедушке говорят, что он умер от инфаркта, хотя он покончил с собой)</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="9"> Я пережил тяжелый травмирующий опыт (прежде всего, в раннем детстве, например, ранее отлучение от матери, насилие)</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="10"> Страхи или фобии, которые являются для меня явной проблемой</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="11"> Я испытываю странные, тяжелые чувства, не объяснимые с точки зрения моей реальной жизненной ситуации</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="control2" type="radio" value="12"> Я испытываю чувство вины буквально за все</label>
     
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 8------------------------ -->

<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">8</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Как бы Вы сформулировали, в случае обращения за помощью, свой основной запрос? </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <textarea name="textarea2" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea> 
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 9----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">9</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Проходили ли вы психотерапию за последние 1-2 года?  </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio2" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 10----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">10</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли у вас в настоящее время  </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb1" value="1"> Панические атаки
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb2" value="2"> Клаустрофобия (боязнь замкнутого пространства)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb3" value="3"> Аэрофобия (боязнь перелетов на самолете)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb4" value="4"> Навязчивые мысли и ритуалы (постоянно мыть руки, все время перепроверять утюг/ключи и т.п)
        <p></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkb51" value="5"> Другое
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea3" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>

<!-- 11----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">11</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Принимаете ли вы антидепрессанты, транквилизаторы   </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl4" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl4" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 12----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">12</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Не так давно я пережил тяжелую для себя ситуацию   </span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl5" type="radio" value="Y"> Да</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl5" type="radio" value="N"> Нет</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 13----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">13</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Консультирование в каком виде вы предпочтете (все виды консультирования не привязаны к вашему географическому положению и доступны из любой точки мира)</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="1"> Индивидуальное консультирование (целенаправленное решение наболевших проблем с профессионалом)</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="2"> Он-лайн проект (аудио-, видео- в записи), который позволяет всесторонне изменить жизнь за полгода, самостоятельно или с поддержкой профессионала </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl13" type="radio" value="3"> Я хочу работать только очно, и готов совместить коучинг с поездкой на Адриатику (Черногория), вышлите мне, пожалуйста, больше информации (проект «Коучинг на Адриатике»)</label>
        <p></p>
   
     </td>
     
</tr>
<!-- 14----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">14</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Я знаю про проект Евгении Соловьевой «Место Силы и Любви»</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="1"> первый день</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="2"> 1-2 месяца</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="3"> около полугода</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="4"> менее года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="5"> 1-2 года</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="6"> 3-5 лет</label>
    <p></p>
    <label><input name="radio4" type="radio" value="7"> давно</label>
    <p></p>
   
     </td>
     </tr>
<!-- 15----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">15</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Укажите, пожалуйста, Ваш город</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
       <p>
         <input type="text" required name="city" >
       </p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 16----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">16</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span> Ваша должность / кем Вы работаете?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
       <input type="text"  name="work" >
       <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 17----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">17</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш e-mail</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <input type="email" required name="emailaddr" >
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 18----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">18</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Я узнал о вас из</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="1"> От знакомых </label>
        <p></p>
        <label> Интернет: </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="2"> Яндекс</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="3"> Google</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="4"> YouTube</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="5"> Вконтакте</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="6"> Facebook</label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radio6" type="radio" value="7"> Другие сайты</label>
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 19----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">19</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Какую информацию вы искали, когда нашли проект «Место Силы и Любви»?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea4" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 20----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">20</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Укажите, как бы Вы хотели получить наши рекомендации?</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <label><input name="radioControl7" type="radio" value="1"> Прошу прислать мне рекомендации по электронной почте </label>
        <p></p>
        <label><input name="radioControl7" type="radio" value="2"> Позвоните мне, пожалуйста, я хочу обсудить варианты работы по Скайп (в течение 1-2 дней)</label>
        <p></p>
       
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 21----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">21</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Ваш Skype</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <input type="text" required name="skype" >
        <p></p>
           
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- 22----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="right" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span class="circle">22</span></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;"><span>Есть ли еще что-то, о чем вы хотели сообщить нам</span>
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <p>
         <textarea name="textarea5" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> 
        </p>
           
     </td>
</tr>
<!--- Result----------------------- -->
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     
</tr>
<tr > 
     <td align="left" width="0" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
         
     </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" style="border-width: 0px;border:none none;">
             
        <button type="submit" class="blueButton" > Результат </button>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>

</fieldset>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Мучалась столько дней :)
А есть возможность обойтись без скрола, чтобы текст на следующую строку переносился? Наверное тут пробелма в том, что у меня не просто текст, а еще input type="checkbox"  и "radio"

Comment: И overflow-wrap: break-word; не работает для этого случая?

Comment: Уберите у элементов textarea атрибуты col и row, а ширину и высоту им в css задайте. Именно они задают ширину всего сейчас.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю!!!